# Error when calling .processQueue() in Dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzoneJS in my project. In the `addedfile` event I've added:

```
    var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
    $.ajax({
        async: true,                      
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '../public/userfiles',
        data: {"_token": csrf  },
        complete: function(data) {
            var maxsize = 314572800;
            var freesize = maxsize - data.responseJSON;
            if(file.size > freesize){
                alert('Нямата достатъчно свободно пространсво.');
            }
            else {
                alert('Успешно качен файл');
                return Dropzone.prototype.processQueue();         
            }
        }
    });
```

This actually get the summed up sizes of all the uploaded files and checks wheter the currently uploaded file is larger than the 'free space'. I've set on false the autoProcessQueue option in order to make the check. After checking the size I call the function which should proceed the queue. But the last line `return Dropzone.prototype.processQueue();` gives me an error in the console saying

`TypeError: this.options is undefined
parallelUploads = this.options.parallelUploads;`
What could be the case?
EDIT: 
[image]

Comment: You need to call `processQueue` on a `Dropzone` instance. If `this` isn't an instance of `Dropzone`, how will it know which queue to process?

Comment: Doesn't `Dropzone.prototype.processQueue();` do the job?

Comment: When a function is on the prototype, that means that instances of that class need to be used. Think of it this way, you could have multiple dropzones on your page. How would `Dropzone.prototype.processQueue` know which one you meant?

Answer (score 1):

`processQueue` only works when it's called on an instance of `Dropzone`. Otherwise, the function has no way of knowing what queue to process. Extending an [example from the docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically):

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  // Your code here
  this.processQueue();
});
```

However, since you're performing this from inside of another function (your `complete` function) you're going to have to make sure you have the right context.

```
myDropzone.on('addedfile', function(file) {
  $.ajax({
    // options go here
    complete: function(data) {
      var maxsize = 314572800;
      var freesize = maxsize - data.responseJSON;
      if(file.size > freesize){
        alert('Нямата достатъчно свободно пространсво.');
      }
      else {
        alert('Успешно качен файл');
        return myDropzone.processQueue();         
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

If you're automatically initializing Dropzone, then you can configure it using the [`init` option.](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events)

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneFileUpload = {
  init: function() {
    // `this` refers to the current dropzone
    var self = this; // keep a reference
    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
      ...
      $.ajax({
        ...
        complete: function(data) {
          var maxsize = 314572800;
          var freesize = maxsize - data.responseJSON;
          if(file.size > freesize){
            alert('Нямата достатъчно свободно пространсво.');
          }
          else {
            alert('Успешно качен файл');
            return self.processQueue();         
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: actually where exactly in the dropzone.js file should I put this. Because it gives me `Error: Invalid dropzone element.
throw new Error("Invalid dropzone element.");`

Comment: @Alex This shouldn't go in `dropzone.js`, it should go in your code. How exactly do you initialize Dropzone?

Comment: Yeah, put it in my main .js file and `Error: Dropzone already attached.
throw new Error("Dropzone already attached.");`

Comment: @Alex Then you're already attaching Dropzone some other time. My guess is with jQuery. Again, **how exactly do you initialize Dropzone?** Ignoring all of my code, what are you doing in *your* code to startup Dropzone?

Comment: In the index.php
 `<form  action="{{ URL::to('upload') }}" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFileUpload">
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" />
</form>`

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer to work for your situation. If the `init` function isn't called, try matching up your form ID with the ID of the example on the Dropzone site.

Comment: @Alex No. You should pretty much never modify library code ever. Run this in your own code. So make your own file like "main.js" or something then include that *after* you've included dropzone.js.

Comment: Dude, admire your help, but I just can't make it. Again it says that dropzone is already attached. In the question i've added an image with the new code.

Comment: @Alex From your edit: Notice how in my edit I'm not initializing a new instance of Dropzone anymore. Remove `var myDropzone = new Dropzone(...)` and change `myDropzone` to `self`.

Comment: Mike, you are a pure JS guru. It works now. THANKS a million for the time you spent for my problem!!! Still no idea why it worked but thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `processQueue` from your Dropzone instance
`var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");`

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
$.ajax({
    async: true,                      
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '../public/userfiles',
    data: {"_token": csrf  },
    complete: function(data) {
        var maxsize = 314572800;
        var freesize = maxsize - data.responseJSON;
        if(file.size > freesize){
            alert('Нямата достатъчно свободно пространсво.');
        }
        else {
            alert('Успешно качен файл');
            return myDropzone.processQueue();         
        }
    }
});
```

and not from global Dropzone class

see: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-autoProcessQueue